# How to check Disk information of EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wanted to compare the disk performance of AWS EBS with other system, can someone help me to find out the count of cylinders and head of harddisk.

I tried the following , but not working.

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/xvda1

/dev/xvda1:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Wouldn't have thought that the head/cylinder information on EBS is of any interest for performance.  Probably you need to read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Storage.html and understand that EBS is network attached

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Linux Command `fdisk -l` will show you the information about cylinders and head count.

[image: Example]

Comment: 255 heads seems legit.